# Uncaught TypeError: Object function () has no method 'replace'

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectbox

I'm using a jQuery chained select dropdown box from **[this site](http://koviko.net/tutorial/building-an-accessible-client-side-chained-selection-drop-down)/[script](http://koviko.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/jquery.dynamicDropdown.js)**. I put it in the sidebar and it works fine on the homepage but it isn't working on post pages and the debugger points out this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ()
{for(var a=[];this.length;)a.push(this.splice(Math.random()*this.length,1));
for(;a.length;)this.push(a.pop());return this} has no method 'replace'
```

It says there's an error in `escapeQuotes : function(str) {return str.replace(/([""\\])/g, "\\$1");`

The beginning of the script:

```
(function($) {
  $.dynamicDropdown = {
    /**
     * Escape quotation marks and slashes
     * @param {String} String to format
     * @return {String}
     */
    escapeQuotes : function(str) {
      return str.replace(/([""\\])/g, "\\$1");
    },
```

Here's how I call the function. I'm using a json file to pull the options text and value into the selected boxes :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON('suggest.json', function(data){

        var $select = $('#mySelectID');

        $.each(data, function (index, o) {
            var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.Box1ID + ":" + o.Box3).text(o.Box1 + "|" + o.Box2 + "|" + o.Box3);
            $select.append($option);
        });

        $("#mySelectID").dynamicDropdown({"delimiter":"|"});

    });
});
```

Edited:

It seems that there's a conflict with a random image rotator I just put on the site. I temporarily removed the rotator and the chained select box is working fine. Here's an [example](http://painfulmouth.com/index2.php) to show the error. And [this](http://painfulmouth.com/index3.php) is without the random rotator.

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
                var s = [];
                while (this.length) s.push(this.splice(Math.random() * this.length, 1));
                while (s.length) this.push(s.pop());
                return this;
            }

            var picData = [
                ['img1','url_1'],
                ['img2','url_2'],
                ['img3','url_3'],

            picO = new Array();
            randIndex = new Array();  //array of random indexes
            for(i=0; i < picData.length; i++){
                picO[i] = new Image();
                picO[i].src = picData[i][0];
                picO[i].alt = picData[i][1];
                randIndex.push(i);
            }
            randIndex.shuffle();
            window.onload=function(){
                var mainImgs = document.getElementById('carouselh').getElementsByTagName('img');


                for(i=0; i < mainImgs.length; i++){
                    mainImgs[i].src = picO[randIndex[i]].src; //assign a random image
                    mainImgs[i].parentNode.href = picData[randIndex[i]][1];
                    mainImgs[i].alt = picData[randIndex[i]][1];
                }

            }
```

Comment: `str` is either an array, an object, null or false.

Comment: A wrong value is passed to `escapeQuotes`. `str` is a function instead of a string. Make sure you are calling the function correctly, i.e. pass a string (since you don't show how the function is called, that's all there is to say).

Comment: @FelixKling thank you. I just added additional details.

Comment: Could you put up a Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.com

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to be the cause of the problem. Where is this function `function ()
{for(var a=[];this.length;)a.push(this.splice(Math.random()*this.length,1));
for(;a.length;)this.push(a.pop());return this}` defined/coming from? That's where the problem is.

Comment: @FelixKling It's from a random image rotator I just put on the site. I removed it and the selected box is working again. I just setup an [example](http://painfulmouth.com/index2.php) to show the confliction.

Comment: @user35295: Yep, that's the problem. Extending `Array.prototype` is a bad idea. Just convert it to a function that accepts the array as argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in [this script](http://koviko.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/jquery.dynamicDropdown.js) which you use, the problem is most likely in these lines of code:

```
for (var i in parts) {
      name += "[\"" + $.dynamicDropdown.escapeQuotes(parts[i]) + "\"]";
  ...
}
```

The point is, do not iterate over an array using `for in` loop, since there is probably a function added to the `Array.prototype` which shows up in `for in` loop over the array, simply change it to:

```
for (var i=0;i<parts.length;i++) {
      name += "[\"" + $.dynamicDropdown.escapeQuotes(parts[i]) + "\"]";
  ...
}
```

then this won't cacth that function any more.

---

as you added to your post, the reason is exactly what I have pointed out. but if you still insist on using `for in` loop, you should check the type of `parts[i]` like this:

```
for (var i in parts) {
      if(typeof parts[i] != "string") continue;
      name += "[\"" + $.dynamicDropdown.escapeQuotes(parts[i]) + "\"]";
  ...
}
```

you have the same problem with another `for in` loop:

```
for (var i in options) {
    option = $(document.createElement("option"))
      .val($.isArray(options[i]) ? i : options[i])
      .html(i)
      .appendTo(select);
}
```

change it to `for (var i=0;i<options.length;i++)` or add this:

```
if(typeof options[i] != "string") continue;
```

to the first line of your for loop.

Comment: Thank you. It's working. I followed your advice, but the modifications seem to add an additional option "shuffle" in all the dropdown boxes. ([example](http://painfulmouth.com/index4.php)) Is it possible to get rid of that?

Comment: @user35295: regarding this problem, I updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but when I added either method the selected box was broken and an error occured. The first one says `Uncaught ReferenceError: parts is not defined`. It looks like `setting` and `parts` are defined after the option's `for in loop`. The second method returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement`. Is that

Comment: @user35295: I think you have used, `for(var i=0;i<parts.length;i++)`, which was my mistake, if you see I have changed it to `for (var i=0;i<options.length;i++)`